# C++ String manipulation - if stament

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I have the following code that works correctly. However after I add an else statement anything always evaluates to else

```
wgetstr(inputWin, ch); //get line and store in ch variable
        str = ch;          //make input from char* to string


        if(str=="m" || str=="M"){
            showFeedback("Data Memory Updated");
        }
        if(str=="p" || str=="P"){
            showFeedback("Program Memory Updated");
        }
        if(str=="g" || str=="G"){
            showFeedback("Accumulator, Program Counter, Zero Result Updated");
        }
        if(str=="e" || str=="E"){
            showFeedback("Editing Mode Enabled");
        }
        if(str=="c" || str=="C"){
            showFeedback("Program Copied Into Program Memory");
        }
        if(str=="r" || str=="R"){
            showFeedback("Executing Program");
        }
        if(str=="x" || str=="X"){
            showFeedback("Program Exited");
        }
```

All the previous evaluates correctly based on what the input is. i.e If I enter "m" it calls the showeFeedback("Data Memory Updated") on so on, but if I add the following else statement, I always get "Invalid Command Entered" no matter what I enter.

```
else{
            showFeedback("Invalid Command Entered");
        }
```

Comment: this is unrelated to your problem, but you might consider transforming your str to upper (or lower) case so that you don't have all those ||s in your conditionals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of those are separate if-statements.  The else you added only goes with the last one.  Change all but the first if to `else if` and it should work like you expect.

Comment: you're so right. I don't know how I did this. I'm not that noob. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use else if for everything except the first one.

So the simple change to your existing code:

```
        if(str=="m" || str=="M"){
            showFeedback("Data Memory Updated");
        }
        else if(str=="p" || str=="P"){
            showFeedback("Program Memory Updated");
        }
        else if(str=="g" || str=="G"){
            showFeedback("Accumulator, Program Counter, Zero Result Updated");
        }
        else if(str=="e" || str=="E"){
            showFeedback("Editing Mode Enabled");
        }
        else if(str=="c" || str=="C"){
            showFeedback("Program Copied Into Program Memory");
        }
        else if(str=="r" || str=="R"){
            showFeedback("Executing Program");
        }
        else if(str=="x" || str=="X"){
            showFeedback("Program Exited");
        }
        else
        {
            showFeedback("Invalid Command Entered");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to use the `switch` statement that exists exactly for this kind of needs..

eg:

```
char str = ch[0];

switch (str)
{
    case 'm':
    case 'M': { showFeedback("Data Memory Updated"); break; }
    case 'p':
    case 'P': { showFeedback("Program Memory Updated"); break; }
    ....
    default: { showFeedback("Invalid Command Entered"); }
    /* default case is choosen if noone of the above is selected */
}
```

EDIT:
just to explain your doubt in the comment, `char str = ch[0]` means *take first character of the string and put it here*.

if you want to check the complete string doing direct comparisons (with `==` or `!=`) is not adeguate: you should use `strcmp(char* str1, char* str2)` function that returns `0` if the two strings are equal.

Comment: yes i tried that but if i enter something like "mem" it will call case 'm' for some reason

Comment: "some reason" is that checking just first character of a string won't assume anything about the rest.. so "m" or "mem" or "mwhatever" will be just the same. It's a sort of *if string begins with 'm' character*

Comment: my snippet is not working on strings, actually.
And as you can see there is "char str", next time before downvoting please try to get into the problem.

Comment: Btw, this is C++, and I think the questioner's `str` is probably a string class, since the comment "make input from char* to string" suggests to me that "char*" and "string" are different things. So `==` and `!=` should be adequate. I agree with the rest of this, though, switching on a char is the obvious thing since all commands a single-char. Could add a check that the input isn't longer than one char: your code processes "go" the same as "g", while the questioner's code rejects "go" as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you add the else, its against the if(str=="x" || str=="X") line - so anything that is not an X will hit the else statement.

I think what you want are to convert all those ifs to "else if", except the first one of course.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, you may want to use toupper to convert your string to uppercase so that you don't have to OR it with lowercase guesses, might make it a little faster.